# Windows Phone 7 & 8: WebBrowser control fails to load web page in iframe after certificate warning

Tags: windows-phone-7, iframe, ssl, windows-phone-8, https

I've done a lot of searching but haven't found any other reports of this specific issue. Please forgive me if this question is a duplicate!

I'm working on a project that involves downloading some HTML from a web service and displaying this HTML in a WebBrowser control in my app. The HTML contains an iframe and looks similar to this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <iframe src="https://some-url" height="600" frameborder="no">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My WebBrowser control:

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Browser" Margin="30" Background="Transparent"
                  IsScriptEnabled="True" ScriptNotify="Browser_ScriptNotify"/>
```

Code behind (pseudo):

```
string myHtml = GetHtmlStringFromServer();
Browser.NavigateToString(myHtml);
```

Problem 1: the site's certificate is not valid, so a certificate warning appears.

Problem 2: after I dismiss the certificate warning by pressing "Continue to website", the page does not load - on WP7 the WebBrowser just goes blank; on WP8 the certificate warning remains.

So, I have two questions:

1. How can I prevent the certificate error from appearing on the device of a consumer who has downloaded my app from the Marketplace? (I'm assuming I can't, but I'd be very glad to hear otherwise.)
2. How can I get the WebBrowser to display the page after the certificate warning has been dismissed? Currently, neither WP7 nor WP8 succeeds :(

I've knocked up a quick app in VS2012 to demonstrate the issue. It uses the web site "https://tv.eurosport.com" which currently has an invalid certificate. You can download the app here:
http://www.filedropper.com/webbrowserssltest

Comment: Does it work ok if using a valid certificate or not SSL?

Comment: @Matt: yes, http://tv.eurosport.com (http) works fine. Also, https://tv.eurosport.com (https) works if I use WebBrowser.Navigate() instead of embedding the URL inside an iframe. The site https://www.verisign.com (https) with a valid certificate also works.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

--> Put your web site's certificate (.cer file) under root folder of your IIS site.

--> In your IIS add mime type for .cer file as file/download

--> Open a regular browser in your windows phone and point to the cer file (e.g., http:\myserver.com\cert.cer). Do NOT use Https

--> Browser will prompt to install certificate. Install it.
Go back to your app and it should work fine.

--> Send me kudos at rg@outlook.in if this worked fine :)

Rahul Gangwar

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your answer but I'm afraid it won't work for me because it's not feasible to instruct every user of the app to install a certificate on their phone manually. I'm starting to wonder whether this problem can be solved at all. Any other ideas?